# How much is the teaching duty of university administrators?

Tags: teaching, university, advisor, administration

Due to the time-consuming nature of administrative jobs, university administrators normally reduce their teaching duties. This reduction is normally proportional to the level of administrative job: Chair/Dean/Vice President/Provost/President.

I am curious if it is only matter of personal preference or there is institutional regulations for minimum and maximum teaching tasks?

In general, how university administrators are involved in classroom teaching, supervising graduate students, and academic research projects?

Comment: In my university system an administrator does not in general teach. A teacher/researcher may do some admin though. Admin personnel are admin specialists (e.g. finance) and typically not familiar with the department subject.

Comment: @PeterJansson the administrators I named `Chair, Dean, Provost` are always academicians.

Comment: They are not considered administrators in my system, those positions are still academic; but your comment clarifies your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that professors in various administrative positions typically have a reduced teaching load. However, this is hard to quantify and depends mostly on the institution's policy and maybe even the specific agreement (or contract) negotiated. The full range is possible: from no reduction in teaching load (position with little time requirement) to full “exemption” from teaching (e.g., dean or university president).

Comment: Not only it vary by institution it can vary by department for Chairs depending on how large the department is.

Comment: For people who come into administrative positions from faculty positions, it's quite common for the administrator to retain their professorial title and to retain the right to return to their tenured faculty position if they ever step down (or are force out of) their administrative position.  In some cases an incoming administrator will negotiate a tenured faculty appointment in addition to their administrative appointment as part of the contract.